# python desktopcouch only works with root account

Tags: python, couchdb, desktopcouch

I'm trying to use this simple example in python:

```
    >>> from desktopcouch.records.server import CouchDatabase
    >>> from desktopcouch.records.record import Record
    >>> db = CouchDatabase('testing', create=True)
    >>>
```

But only works in root account, with a regular user:

```
    >>> from desktopcouch.records.server import CouchDatabase
    >>> from desktopcouch.records.record import Record
    >>> db = CouchDatabase('testing', create=True)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/desktopcouch/application/server.py", line 101, in __init__
    oauth_tokens=oauth_tokens, ctx=ctx)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/desktopcouch/application/server.py", line 75, in __init__
    oauth_tokens=oauth_tokens, ctx=ctx, views_factory=views_factory)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/desktopcouch/records/database.py", line 123, in __init__
    self._reconnect()
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/desktopcouch/application/server.py", line 81, in _reconnect
    port = find_port(ctx=self.ctx)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/desktopcouch/application/platform/__init__.py", line 48, in find_port
    return platform_find_port(pid, ctx)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/desktopcouch/application/platform/linux/__init__.py", line 100, in platform_find_port
    proxy = bus.get_object('org.desktopcouch.CouchDB', '/')
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
    dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken
```

Answer (score 3):

What version of Ubuntu are you using? Only being able to start desktopcouch as root sounds like this bug: [1-line "uri_file =" config fix for CouchDB 1.1.1 compatability](https://bugs.launchpad.net/desktopcouch/+bug/903556)

I proposed a fix for it, but looks like there was some issue with the unit tests (I don't think related to my fix).

Anyway, desktopcouch is now unmaintained and I recommend *not* building any new software upon it. If you're interested in Ubuntu sync as a service, look at [U1DB](http://packages.python.org/u1db/), Canonical's replacement for desktopcouch.

If you're interested in using CouchDB in desktop apps, look at [UserCouch](http://docs.novacut.com/usercouch/index.html) and [Microfiber](http://docs.novacut.com/microfiber/index.html) (disclaimer: I'm the author and maintainer of both). These have both been developed as part of the Novacut project. We were originally using desktopcouch, but have since migrated away from it.